# How to compare char[]array in c# to know if a ward is a Palindrome

Tags: c#, string

I'm trying to insert a word and want to know if it is a polidrom.
Polidrom is a word that if you write it reverse nothing changes like:
1234321 = reverse 1234321
abcddcba = reverse abcddcba
I wrote a code and I dont know what's wrong.
Thanks for your help.

```
  static void Puolidrom(string word)
        {
            string ya = word;
            string ba = word;
            char[] stcArr = ya.ToCharArray();
            char[] stcArr2 = ba.ToCharArray();
            Array.Reverse(stcArr);
            if (stcArr==stcArr2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("poly");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Isn't");
            }
        }
```

Comment: if any answer helped you, please accept it

Answer (score 3):

In your code you're trying to check if one array is same as other array, but you're checking references (`==`) not elements of arrays. Better way will be to check if string and reversed string is the same

use function to reverse string

```
public static string Reverse( string s )
{
 char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();
 Array.Reverse( charArray );
 return new string( charArray );
}
```

and then use it:

```
if(word.Equals(Reverse(word)))
{
    //palindrom
}
else
{
   //not
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to compare char arrays, easier approach would be to create a reverse string with LINQ, then to check if both strings are the same:

```
static bool IsPalindrome(string word)
{
     if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(word))
         return false;

     return word == String.Join("", word.Reverse());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Linq SequenceEqual](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sequenceequal).

Make sure you have `using System.Linq;` in top of your `.cs` file.

```
if (stcArr.SequenceEqual(stcArr2))
{
   Console.WriteLine("poly");
}
else
{
   Console.WriteLine("Isn't");
}
```

Because arrays are reference type ,the `==` operator will check equality of arrays by calling `ReferenceEquals` and not by checking the contents of the arrays.

In your case they dont have same reference so `==` operator will always return false

Comment: that would check for a palindrome, not a polidrome ? (same letters, in 2 words, not the reverse necessarily.)

Comment: nope, it will be always true. stcArr and stcArr2 are the same word (look at the code), so letters are the same

Comment: == operator does not check the elements of array. it will check by reference. @wudzik

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary it is, changed it

Comment: there is no difference between `==` and `Equals`. @wudzik your solution will work with `==` because you converted the char array to string

Comment: Before  comming to If block you should trim the text otherwise the code doesn't work properly.but  despite the problem this is the best code here 1+

Comment: I described the problem that OP is observing. i let the OP to do other modifications (Trim or null check etc...) as he/she wants. @Arashjo

Answer (score 1):

You could write an extension method:

```
public static bool IsPalindrome(this string str1)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str1)) return false;
    return str1.SequenceEqual(str1.Reverse());
}
```

And do:

```
string ya = "word";
bool isPalindrome = ya.IsPalindrome();
```

Comment: comparing two words and saying if one is a palindorme of a second one? Palindrome is a property of a single word, like:  `"word".IsPalindrome()` not  `"word".Palindrome("another")`

Comment: don't need to pass str2. String.Reverse?

Comment: I modified it. It's early.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative solution.

```
    public static bool IsPalindrome(string checkString)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(checkString))
            return false;

        char[] arr = checkString.ToCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length/2; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i] != arr[arr.Length - i - 1])
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```